# TimeDistributed Model Not learning

Tags: keras, convolution, lstm

I am trying to train model to play Chrome Dino (the offline game).

The idea was to have 6 last screenshots of the game, use CNN on each separately (to extract features) and then put those features as timesteps into LSTM.

My training data is X = [6 timestep game screenshots] -> y=[1,0] (keep running, jump)

*Timestep example*

[image: Timestep example]

I have even split the database so it has 50% jump examples and 50% keep running examples.

Sadly I am stuck at 50% accuracy and loss is stuck too.

```
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6944 - acc: 0.4596
Epoch 91/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 92/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 93/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6932 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 94/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6933 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 95/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6942 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 96/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6939 - acc: 0.5000
Epoch 97/100
198/198 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.6935 - acc: 0.5000
```

I have tried many model hyperparams with different layers, but I always get the same result.

Current model

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu'), input_shape=(FRAMES_TO_PROCESS, FRAME_HEIGHT,FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_FILTERS )))

model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(ZeroPadding2D((1,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(64, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2))))

model.add(TimeDistributed(ZeroPadding2D((1,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(ZeroPadding2D((1,1))))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Convolution2D(128, 3, 3, activation='relu')))
model.add(TimeDistributed(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=(2, 2), strides=(2,2))))

model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(TimeDistributed(Flatten()))      

model.add(Dropout(0.1))
model.add(LSTM(120, return_sequences=False))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))

model.compile(loss="categorical_crossentropy", optimizer="adam", metrics=['accuracy'])
```

Any idea what went wrong?